# Referencing a list inside it's inline for loop initialization?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, initialization, inline

I would like to be able to write something like this:

```
x = [0]
x = [x[i-1] for i in range(1,10)]
```

I know this example doesn't make any sense. But I would like to know if it's possible to use previously computed values, while initializing a list in this way. (Perhaps some kind of lambda expression)

Here is the actual code I need:

```
x = [(b[i] - sum([(a[i][j] * x[j]) for j in range(i)])) / a[i][i] for i in range(n)]
```

This gives of course the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

I know there is this way around it:

```
x = []
for i in range(n):                        
    x.append((b[i] - sum([(a[i][j] * x[j]) for j in range(i)])) / a[i][i])
```

But I would really like to know if the first one is possible somehow.

Comment: where are `a` and `b` coming from?

Comment: As arguments of the function. I don't think it's relevant to the question.

Comment: Maybe copy the whole scope of your function, with a sample input and expected output.

Comment: My function works fine, it's a more of a syntax question. I don't have any unexpected outputs or errors. Please read and understand the whole question first.

Comment: Nope, it's not really possible. You see, `x` starts pointing at the list after the list comprehension is evaluated, so practically you are stuck with the regular `for` loop.

Comment: Let me explain - your desired implementation (a one-liner which references itself before it is declared) is impossible. However - what you are trying to do probably has a much simpler/easier/more efficient solution, but to reach it, I will need to understand the scope of your function, and what input/output is expected.

Comment: @RexLakio You can do something freakish, though. Something like: `[x.append((b[i] - sum([(a[i][j] * x[j]) for j in range(i)])) / a[i][i]) for i in range(n)]`. The whole list comprehension will consist of `None`, but `x` will be changed inplace.

Comment: History lesson: there was an implementation-dependent hack you used to be able to do in CPython (<= 2.6) -- list comps had a hidden name like `_[1]`.  But that's gone now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I perfectly agree that what you want is not a good practice. There is a way of doing it (sort of). For example, let's see this:

```
x = [1]
z = [x.append(x[i]*2) for i in range(10)]
```

Now naturally we have:

```
>>> print z
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

but, `x` hold the value we want:

```
>>> print x
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024]
```

So in a similar freakish way you can do:

```
x = [some_init_value]
[x.append((b[i] - sum([(a[i][j] * x[j]) for j in range(i)])) / a[i][i]) for i in range(n)]
```

Note that `x` is changed **inplace** and we do not assign the list comprehension to `x` as the list comprehension will return a bunch of `None`s.

I want to stress that this is **bad**. Good practices state that list comprehensions shouldn't have side effects (as our has).

**EDIT**: Apparently in CPython <= 2.6 you have this "sick hack" where the list comprehension had a hidden value. [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun)'s awesome hack for the Fibonacci sequence:

```
fib = [[0,1][j] if j<2 else locals()['_[1]'][j-1] + locals()['_[1]'][j-2] for j in range(10)]
```

Naturally this fails on CPython 2.7 and PyPy.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I understand that's it's basically pointless as in practice, but I believe it has some great learning value.

Comment: I had this as a comment on the other answer before I noticed your previous comment:  In 2.7+ the bytecode for the comprehension operates on a stack in the execution frame. No dice there. Sick hack in 2.6: `fib = [[0,1][j] if j<2 else locals()['_[1]'][j-1] + locals()['_[1]'][j-2] for j in range(10)]`.

Answer (score 4):

Even if it was possible I don’t think you should even try to do it. The “verbose” three-lines-solution is already quite complicated due to the nested list comprehension which is not even the *outer* part of that line. And you have another sum inside.

I’d actually even split it even more to have the list comprehension separately like this:

```
x = []
for i in range(n):
    k = sum(a[i][j] * x[j] for j in range(i))
    x.append((b[i] - k) / a[i][i])
```

I believe it might be possible to simplify this a bit more, but it’s hard to tell just by looking at it like that without any context on what it actually does, and without example data for `a`, `b` and `n`.

Comment: Thanks, great advice! But it was more of curiosity question, if the nested one-line solution could work somehow.